# Transform PHP multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering if there's any PHP function (or an *elegant* combination of functions), similar to `array_column`, which allows to transform this array:

```
$my_array = array(
  0 => array(
      'film_id' => '19'
      'showing_id' => '525'
  )
  1 => array(
      'film_id' => '117'
      'showing_id' => '507'
  )
  2 => array(
      'film_id' => '19'
      'showing_id' => '526'
  )
  3 => array(
      'film_id' => '117'
      'showing_id' => '510'
  )
)
```

Into this array (the keys now are the `film_id`s of the previous array, and the values are arrays containing all the `showing_id`s associated with each `film_id`):

```
$new_array = array(
  '19' => array(
      0 => '525'
      1 => '526'
  )
  '117 => array(
      0 => '507'
      1 => '510'
  )
)
```

Comment: There also exists a userland implementation of [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column), also linked in the manual (first comment).

Comment: How do you define elegant? One loop or an `array_walk()`  will do it...

Comment: ...like `foreach ($my_array as $a) $new_array[$a['film_id']][] = $a['showing_id'];`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, yes that's *elegant* enough :) A function like the one Mario suggested would be perfect if it was a built-in function, but actually your loop is simpler than I was thinking... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($my_array as $foo){
    $new_array[$foo['film_id']][] = $foo['showing_id'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bogdan, that's exactly what @MichaelBerkowski suggested in his comment ;)